# "RESTEASY008550: Unable to find a CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using the default ValidatorFactor."

Tags: wildfly, cdi

I have tried everything I can think of to get Wild fly to allow me to inject my EJB into my Web Service.  But no matter what I do I get the "**RESTEASY008550: Unable to find a CDI supporting ValidatorFactory.  Using the default ValidatorFactor.**"  Thus CDI will not work.

I have an Ear with a Jar (EJB) and a war (Web Service).

And yes I have a beans.xml (I put it in the EJB and Web Service, again trying anything I can to get the DI to work).

How can I get WildFly to use the CDI ValidatorFactory?

Here is more information:

Ear with a war (Web Service) and a jar (EJB). I have also added a beans.xml file.

EJB:

```
    @Local({MyBeanLocalLookup.class})  //Local interface.
    @Remote({MyBeanRemoteLookup.class})  //Remote Interface
    @Named({ "MyBean" })
    @Stateless
    public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocalLookup, MyBeanRemoteLookup
```

Web Service, I tried both @EJB and @Inject.

```
    @Path("/")
    public class MyService extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    {
        @EJB private MyBeanLocalLookup ejb;
        @Inject private MyBeanLookupLookup ejb2;
        ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Version of WildFly? structure of your deployment? validation.xml present?

Comment: Perhaps: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266464 helps?

Comment: Wildfly 11.  Ear with a war (web service), jar (EJB).  I tried the validation.xml, but nothing.